# In emacs how does the "hyperlink" in the *Help* buffer work?

Tags: emacs, button, elisp, hyperlink

I'm trying to figure out how the "hyperlink" works in the `*Help*` buffer (so that I can implement something similar in the output of M-x compile). Here is a more detailed description of the behaviour I want to imitate:
`M-x describe-function find-file` opens up a `*Help*` buffer. The first line of this buffer (for me) shows: `find-file is an interactive Lisp function in files.el.` files.el is underlined and clicking (or hitting enter when point is there) opens a new buffer with files.el and the point positioned at the definition of `find-file`. Doing a describe-key for  says  invokes push-button in button.el, which tells me `Perform the action specified by a button at location pos` - but how do I define a button and associate an action with that button in my own buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major mode of the `*Help*` buffers is `help-mode`. In its source code (`help-mode.el`), you find function `help-make-xrefs` that *"Parse[s] and hyperlink[s] documentation cross-references in the given BUFFER"*. You may check it how it was implemented.

Otherwise, I'd suggest using `org-mode` instead, which uses the simple form `[[URI][caption]]` to [mark hyperlinks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Link-format.html#Link-format).

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I debugged the code in compile mode, realised there is a way for me to specify a regexp (in compilation-error-regexp-alist) that'll allow me to add additional patterns which would be used by compile mode to create cross references.